# Bug in XCode debugger?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios-simulator

I am working on an iPhone app which is using an external library for which I have the source. During debugging some of the objects are listed as 0x0 in the debugger but the app runs fine. Also, some of the objects addresses point to the wrong thing. 
These symbols are in the external library. The addresses are fine if I am tracing through a file actually in the external library.

Does anyone have suggestions how to stop this behavior?

Comment: I believe an object with the memory address of 0x0 is nil - that's not an error.

Comment: I do know that it is nil. The program should have promptly crashed because I was reading those objects. That's what's amazing me.

It is not because I do not know what 0x0 is. I know what it is which is why it's amazing.

Comment: It is legal to derefernce nil in ObjC. It shouldn't crash. It will silently do nothing.

Comment: Rob,

As I said the problem is not with the program. It's with the XCode debugger. The program's running as well as I expect it to. My objects are being properly accessed but debugger insists there is nothing.

Comment: I think this requires a visit to bugreporter.apple.com.  I am seeing similar behavior when building under the MacOS 10.7 sdk with Xcode 4.2.1   And I wish I could rate down comments that try to explain an IDE bug with false programmer error scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  target settings > Build tab > GCC 4.2 Code Generation > "Compile for Thumb"

I turned off this target setting and the gdb problem went away.

--

Hi John.

I understand what you're referring to.  I'm also seeing a problem where gdb and NSLog() are giving me different results for pointers in certain parts of my code.

In a boiled-down example, gdb fails to report the proper value for "pointer" when I set a breakpoint on any line in this function:

```
id testPointer( id pointer )
{
    NSLog( @"pointer value: %p", pointer );

    @try
    {
        NSLog( @"foo" );
    }
    @catch ( NSException *e )
    { }
    @finally
    { }

    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem under Xcode 4.2.1 while building under the MacOS 10.7 SDK.  Which I could just turn compile for thumb off for success!  I do that routinely anyway when compiling for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As zPesk notes, 0x0 is nil, which is a common value for objects that have not been initialized (particularly instance variables). I'm not certain what you mean by "point to the wrong thing." If you haven't initialized a local (stack) variable, it may point to any random address until it is initialized. What behavior are you having trouble with?

Comment: It is pointing to the wrong thing in the sense that the pointers I see in the debugger are pointing to other things which I know about, but those pointers should never point there.

I have been working for some time on the program and this is the first time it's ever happened. I tried checking the debuggers lazy symbol loading to no avail.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you have found a bug in gdb here. Perhaps more details of the code and what gdb is returning would help a lot here. You don't have compiler optimizations turned on do you? That can always lead to surprising debugger results.

Comment: Also, if you doubt what gdb is telling you, you should always add NSLog() statements and compare the results.

Comment: Bug in gdb: unlikely. Bug in xcode: possible. Crappy design of xcode that makes debugger lie to you without you realizing it: definitely. I call that a bug, though some would not.

Answer (score 0):

Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I, too, am noticing strange behavior in gdb when mixing Thumb and ARM modes. For example, it appears that the addresses of variables reported by gdb are off by exactly 64 bytes from the addresses reported using printf("%p\n") statements. Perhaps gdb needs to be explicitly told whether the current operating mode is ARM or Thumb...?