# Why does GDB show ObjC superclass instance variables as NULL?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, gdb

I have an Objective-C with ARC project in XCode 4.  I have a custom base class MyBaseClass with several __strong NSString * properties (such as superClassString) which are inherited by several subclasses (i.e MySubClass).  Even after immediately providing an object for one of the properties:

```
instance = [[MySubClass alloc] init];
instance.superClassString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gdb victim"];
```

GDB still reports the pointer value (instance.superClassString) as being NULL.  It will even report the pointer value as NULL even if I break before a function that explicitly uses the pointer:

```
NSLog(@"It really is there: %@", instance.superClassString);
```

The system correctly displays the text:

```
  gdb victim
```

and acts as if nothing were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in XCode / gdb itself. Happened to me several times as well. Just verify if you're compiling in Debug and not in release mode.

This might help: [Bug in XCode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285708/bug-in-xcode-debugger)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to visit bugreporter.